# Get category image without object manager

Tags: magento-2.1, category, fatal-error, category-attribute, object-manager

I previously used `ObjectManager` to get current category image. but it sometimes caused problems to me. Like loading blank page without no content, slower loading time etc.. , also I saw in a few questions that people commented that using `ObjectManager` directly is not a good approach.

This is the page source when I get blank page error.

```
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<br />
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getImageUrl() on null in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\app\design\frontend\abcvendor\abctheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\brandlogoimage.phtml:37
    Stack trace:
    #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include()
    #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php-&gt;render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor), 'E:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
    #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\var\generation\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor.php(544): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template-&gt;fetchView('E:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor-&gt;fetchView('E:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Abstrac in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\abc\app\design\frontend\abcvendor\abctheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\brandlogoimage.phtml</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
```

This is the code I used to get category in my page, I used phtml file.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category'); ?> 
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="brandlogo" /></a>
```

How can I prevent that blank page loading error?

Is there any better approach to get category image than method I've used here?

Answer (score 2):

try this code its work for me

add this code in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml file and check

```
 $product = $block->getProduct();

$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
    echo $cat->getName();?>
    <img src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ?>" height="100" width="100">
<?php
    }
?>
```

***Please override product detail page.***

Comment: did you get the required result?

Comment: Yes, I can get result from using ObjectManager, But I need to get this **without** using ObjectManager. Thanks for all your help, But I'm going to try as good as I can to avoid using objectManager

Comment: i have update the code please check

Comment: did you get the result?

Comment: It's irrelevant if he got the result or not. It's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Its not working. and even its irrelevant approach to get the images

Answer (score 0):

You can create Block class in which you can get current category like:

```
    namespace Namespace\Module_Name\Block;

class Subcategories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    /**
     * Subcategories constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }


    public function getCategoryCollection(){
        $_category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());

        return $collection;
    }


}
```

And you can call this function in your phtml file  like:

```
    $category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
//------------OR--------------------
    $categoryCollection = $block->getCategoryCollection();
    $category->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: Now I get this error,           Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getImageUrl() on null

Comment: this might be because if you are not getting the current category, I think

Comment: can you please check the print_r($category->getData()) if your getting the current category or not?

Comment: how to fix that? when using object manager approach, I get category image first but after few page refreshes, its gone and I get same error

Comment: whats the error

Comment: I tried var_dump($category); result is NULL. any way to fix that?


previous Error is mentioned in my question.

Comment: You want current category image in your phtml file right?

Comment: yes, image URL. I even tried echo $category->getName(); got error Call to a member function getName() on null

Comment: This code will only work if you are on any category page or product page

Comment: try this on any category page

Comment: I need to get category image for a product. category image for certain product that it belongs to. Im in detail page

Comment: You mean you are on product detail page and you want the respective product categroy image?

Comment: yes, I can get category image on category page, but get problems in detail page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67755/discussion-between-mandar-parbate-and-joey).